# Calculating Expected Value.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

Let a random variable X has a following distribution:

$$f_X(x)=\frac{x}{\theta}\exp(\frac{-x^2}{2\theta}),x>0.$$

It can be shown that $\mathbb E(X)=(\theta\pi/2)^{(1/2)},$ $\mathbb E(X^2)=2 \theta$ and $\mathbb E(X^4)=8 \theta^2$ .

I have to find method of moments(MoM) estimator for $\theta$ and the bias of the MoM estimator.

I found MoM estimator for  $\theta$ to be:

$$\bar X=(\tilde\theta\pi/2)^{(1/2)}$$
$$\Rightarrow \bar X^2=\tilde\theta\pi/2$$
$$\Rightarrow \tilde\theta=2\bar X^2/\pi.$$

But I am having difficulty to find the bias. I tried as follows:

Bias of MoM $=\mathbb E(\tilde\theta)-\theta=\mathbb E(2\bar X^2/\pi)-\theta=\frac{2}{\pi}\mathbb E(\bar X^2)=\frac{2}{\pi}\mathbb E[(1/n\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)^2]=\frac{2}{\pi n^2} \mathbb E[(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)^2]$

Could you please tell me how can I simplify the $E[(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)^2]$ term?

Comment: $\left(\sum _i^n X_i\right){}^2=2 \sum _{i=1}^{n-1} \sum _{j=i+1}^n X_i X_j+\sum _{i=1}^n X_i^2$.

Comment: @JimB Are there steps to get the right hand side or is it just a formula?

Comment: One way to get the right-hand side is to use induction.  However, I would imagine that for whatever class you need this, just taking the formula as "truth" is probably good enough.